# How to make Pyinstaller launch PowerShell under Windows Terminal instead of stand-alone PowerShell?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

The question pretty much tells the story.

I have a console application I need to run in PowerShell under Windows Terminal.  This, due to Windows Terminal solving a bunch of the rendering, code page and other issues one runs into if running PowerShell on its own.

The best idea I can come up with at the moment is to manually create a batch file that would effectively launch the exe crated by Pyinstaller using Windows Terminal.  That's my next experiment.

Another --probably crazy-- idea is to wrap the console application in a wxPython application and see if there's a way to render a proper terminal in that context.  Probably not the best idea.

Comment: A wxPython application (which I assume runs (as if) with `pythonw.exe`, i.e. as a GUI application) that launches `wt.exe` should work (`wt.exe` is itself a GUI application that opens Windows Terminal).

Comment: Re: your previous comment (that thread really shouldn't have been closed with that dupe) - yes, your current idea is on the right track - for non-technical users, make your application NOT a console application (i.e. use that `-w` flag anyway) and then the entry point that Pyinstaller launches will instead open the console/virtual terminal of your (or your users') choice, with the intended application running in it.

Comment: Right now I have the batch file approach working.  It flashes a CMD window and then launches into PowerShell under Windows Terminal and runs just fine.  I took all of this and created an MSI that allows the user to double-click-install.  This gives them a desktop icon that launches the batch file.  And, of course, they can go to the control panel and uninstall the whole thing.  I will try the -w flag tomorrow and see if I can get it to run a little cleaner.  The flashing CMD window isn't going to bother anyone...but it does bother me.

Comment: Re. the closed question.  Yeah, SO can be weird sometimes.  No big deal.  Every time I see something like that happen my first thought is always the same:  Someone is going to come along with the same problem and they will never see this question asked if I don't try to get it through.  I do my best to attempt to help others with the questions I ask...because some of this stuff can burn so much time if someone doesn't give you a shove in the right direction.